# My treeset seems to have a size value of 1, where it should be undefined

Tags: java, applet, iterator, set, treeset

For some reason, my list will only allow one element. when i delete the element, it allows creation of another, but i cannot ever have two circles at once.

Here is the applet:

```
import java.applet.Applet;import java.awt.Graphics;import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;import java.awt.event.ActionListener;import java.util.Iterator;import java.util.Random;import java.util.Set;import java.util.TreeSet; import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Game extends Applet implements ActionListener{
    int b_width=500, b_height=500;
    int counter=0;
    Random gen=new Random(); Timer T; Set circles;

    public void init() {
        setSize(b_width, b_height); circles = new TreeSet(); 
    }
    public void circleConstr(){
        Circle cl=new Circle(b_width,(int)(gen.nextDouble()*b_height), gen.nextInt()%190, -1);
        circles.add(cl);
        Circle cr=new Circle(0, (int)(gen.nextDouble()*b_height), gen.nextInt()%190, 1);
        circles.add(cr);
    }
```

so there ^^^ it should have made two circles, but it only eer makes one.

```
    public void circleMover(Set circles){
        Iterator<Circle> i=circles.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
           Circle c=i.next();c.move();
           if(c._x>b_width+b_width/5||c._x<b_width/5||c._y>b_height+b_height/5||c._y<-b_height/5){i.remove();}
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Iterator<Circle> i=circles.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            i.next().paint(g);
        } 
    }
    public void start(){    
       T = new Timer(100, this); //calls actionpreformed every .01 seconds(10 miliseconds)
       T.start(); //starts timer   
    }
```

up there is the timer and painter

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(counter%5==0){
            circleConstr();    
        }
```

additionally here ^^^^, it should be creating a new circle every .5 seconds, but instead waits until the first circle is killed.

```
        counter++;
        circleMover(circles);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Here is the circle class:

```
import java.awt.Color;import java.awt.Graphics;import      java.util.Random;

public class Circle implements Comparable {
    int _x, _y, _yb, _sp, multiplier; double _m,  _radiusRandom gen=new Random();
    int r=(int)(gen.nextDouble()*255), b=(int)(gen.nextDouble()*255), g=(int)(gen.nextDouble()*255);
    public Circle (int x, int y, int range, int multiplier){
        _x=x;_y=y;
        _radius=(int)(gen.nextDouble()*range); if(_radius<0){_radius*=-1;}
        _m=gen.nextDouble()+gen.nextInt()%2+.5;_sp=(int)(gen.nextDouble()*7)+1;_sp*=multiplier;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics h){
        Color color= new Color (r, b, g); 
        h.setColor(color);
        h.fillOval(_x, _y, (int)_radius, (int) _radius);
    }
    public void move(){
        _x+=_sp; _y=(int)(_m*_x+_yb);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object t) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set` will not allow more than one element that compares `equal`.  Your use of [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) will have it relying on calling `compareTo`.

> [A] TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method

You do have `compareTo` defined in `Circle`.  However, your `compareTo` method is always returning `0`, so *all* your `Circle` objects will compare equal to each other, and only one will make it in to your `TreeSet`.

You will need to properly define your `compareTo` method.

In addition, you may want to use the generics on the `TreeSet` class and implementing the generic form of `Comparable` in `Circle`, e.g.:

```
Set<Circle> circles;
```

and

```
circles = new TreeSet<Circle>();
```

Then in `Circle`:

```
public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
```

and

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Circle t) {
    // Return -1, 0, or 1 if this object <, equal, or > than "t"
}
```